# Lustre MDT full, rm: cannot remove No space left on device

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems, lustre

I have a production server with lustre file system in it. It has 2 OSTs and one MDT. Now i my MDT is full. I can't delete my old files.

Here a snapshot of my lustre file system.

```
$ lfs df -i
UUID                      Inodes       IUsed       IFree IUse% Mounted on
data-MDT0000_UUID       28002745    28002745           0 100% /mnt/data[MDT:0]
data-OST0000_UUID       78818692    13987183    64831509  18% /mnt/data[OST:0]
data-OST0001_UUID       78823552    13987089    64836463  18% /mnt/data[OST:1]

filesystem_summary:     28002745    28002745           0  18% /mnt/data
```

We can't buy new MDT in the near future, so our best hope is to delete some old files.

But when we try to delete the files, we always get these error

```
rm -rf *
rm: cannot remove ‘/foo/bar/file1.png’: No space left on device
rm: cannot remove ‘/foo/bar/file2.png’: No space left on device
```

We have tried these method but it fails,
["rm: can not remove xxx: No Space left on device" on BTRFS](https://serverfault.com/questions/478733/rm-can-not-remove-xxx-no-space-left-on-device-on-btrfs)

Looks like lustre have different metadata from BTRFS.

How can we delete our files?

**Edit**
We are adding two hard drive (sda sdc) to existing MDS server, and creating new mds with it. And tried to attach it to our existing lustre file system.

```
mkfs.lustre --mdt \
   --fsname data \
   --index 1 \
   --mgsnode 20.20.2.1@o2ib \
   --servicenode 20.20.2.1@o2ib \
   --backfstype=zfs \
   mdt1pool/mdt1 \
   mirror sda sdc

mkdir -p /lustre/mdt1 && mount -t lustre mdt1pool/mdt1 /lustre/mdt1
```

But it returns this error.

```
mount.lustre: mount mdt1pool/mdt1 at /lustre/mdt1 failed: No space left on device
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to delete one file first? **'*'** is manipulated differently in bash, and since no space available it can't create tmp file too,
Hope it will help you.

Comment: i've tried to delete one file with rm or unlink. But no luck. It seems my best bet is adding storage directly to my zpool.